Problem with undefined symbol in QT6 in Archlinux
I installed anki with AUR package in this link: https://aur.archlinux.org/anki.git
But after install I see that's application is not launching,
I'm stuck how to resolve that "undefined symbol" problem in PyQT.
Below you can see the output of calling anki application from bash:
[user@host anki]$ anki
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/anki", line 5, in <module>
    from aqt import run
  File "/usr/lib/python3.12/site-packages/aqt/__init__.py", line 54, in <module>
    from aqt import gui_hooks
  File "/usr/lib/python3.12/site-packages/aqt/gui_hooks.py", line 11, in <module>
    from _aqt.hooks import *
  File "/usr/lib/python3.12/site-packages/_aqt/hooks.py", line 18, in <module>
    from aqt.qt import QDialog, QEvent, QMenu, QModelIndex, QWidget, QMimeData
  File "/usr/lib/python3.12/site-packages/aqt/qt/__init__.py", line 20, in <module>
    from .qt6 import *
  File "/usr/lib/python3.12/site-packages/aqt/qt/qt6.py", line 17, in <module>
    from PyQt6.QtQuick import *
ImportError: /usr/lib/python3.12/site-packages/PyQt6/QtQuick.abi3.so: undefined symbol: _ZNK11QSGMaterial9viewCountEv, version Qt_6

I tried to call anki from bash and saw output with error, tried to reinstall pyqt5, 6 versions but that didn't help.

This has clearly got nothing to do with programming. It looks like you need to update your system properly and use the official pyqt packages. As an arch linux user, you should know that if you break your system by installing unofficial packages, it's your responsibility to work out how to fix it. If you can't do that yourself, take it to the arch linux forum.

okay, usually all goes well when downloading aur packages and download/update all dependencies, but in that case not, so you recommend to use official pyqt packages, I will try later, thanks!
